# What exactly does this part of code do?

Tags: theming

There is a code snippet in a .twig file that I can't understand.

Here is the code:

```
{% set show_emer_alert = 'ALL CLEAR' in page.emergency|render ? 'N' : 'Y' %}

{% if show_emer_alert == 'Y' %}
     {{ page.emergency }}
{% endif %}
```

I know that this one `{% if show_emer_alert == 'Y' %}` is a condition, But I can't get how it becomes `Y` or `N`.

Can you please help me understanding what this code does?

Where can I find the page.emergency file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is called a tertiary operator. First, it renders the field page.emergency. Then it checks if the value is equal to `ALL CLEAR'` If it is, then `show_emer_alert` is set to `N`, otherwise it is set to `Y`.

```
{% set show_emer_alert = 'ALL CLEAR' in page.emergency|render ? 'N' : 'Y' %}
```

Tertiary operators act as follows. Imagine the following:

```
$sex = user_is_male($user) ? 'male' : 'female';
```

This code assigns a value to $sex. It does this by executing the function user_is_male(). If this evaluates as `TRUE`, then the value of $sex is set to 'male'. If it evaluates as `FALSE`, then $sex is set to 'female'.

You could do this as well:

```
$male = user_is_male($user);
$sex = $male ? 'male' : 'female';
```

The point is, the first value (before the question mark) is evaluated to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and the value of the variable is set accordingly. The first value, between the question mark and the colon, is used for `TRUE`, and the second value, after the colon, is used for `FALSE`.

In your code a few things happens. First, `page.emergency` is rendered in `page.emergency|render`. This will result in a string value. Next, that string is checked to see if it contains the text `ALL CLEAR`. This is the value that is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If it is `TRUE`, then `show_emer_alert` is set to 'N'. If it is `FALSE`, then `show_emer_alert` is set to `Y`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96963/discussion-on-answer-by-jaypan-what-exactly-does-this-part-of-code-do).